# How can I use async over 3 different array elements

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I want to use Async to perform a function over 3 different arrays.

Currently I have a nested `foreach` loop over the 3 arrays, however that seems to break the actual intention of Async.

This is the method where I'm iterating over the code:

```
    public void newclient(Form f, string[] username, string[] password, string[] server) { 

        foreach(string thisserver in server) {
            foreach (string thispassword in password) {
                foreach (string thisusername in username) {

                    Console.WriteLine(thisserver);

                    Task<string> Task = SpawnClient(f, thisusername, thispassword, thisserver);
                    Console.WriteLine(Task);
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the Async method it's calling:

```
   public async Task<string> SpawnClient(Form f, string nextusername, string nextpassword, string nextserver) {

///////////////dostuffhere

    }
```

I have tried playing with things such as `TaskCompletionSource`'s, but I think I'm misunderstanding Async at the moment. It's my first time using it.

Comment: In its current form the nested foreaches just cause the SpawnClient task to run x amount of times.

Comment: so... you're trying all combinations of usernames and passwords on all servers... this ... doesn't sound like something good that we should be helping with ...?

Comment: You probably should be `await`ing those tasks, but it's not clear what you're trying to do here. It actually looks like you're running over every single permutation of username/password/server by the way, I'm not sure you meant to do that?

Comment: @MarcGravell - This was just something I was toying with to do some stuff with the IOT we have in the office (I'm a sysadmin)

Comment: @DavidG - I feel like I'm looking at this wrong with the foreach loops, though.

Comment: So if you have 2 usernames, 2 passwords and 2 servers, you are going to spawn 8 clients here, but I suspect you really want 2, right?

Comment: @DavidG that's correct!

Comment: Then keep the values together as a single object (i.e. a class with username, password and server properties) and loop over a collection of them instead. No need for nested loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want this:

```
List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
foreach(string thisserver in server) {
    foreach (string thispassword in password) {
        foreach (string thisusername in username) {
            Console.WriteLine(thisserver);
            Task<string> task = SpawnClient(f, thisusername, thispassword, thisserver);
            tasks.Add(task);
        }
    }
}
var allResults = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

You'll need to redeclare `newclient` as `async Task` or (only if your `newclient` is an event handler) `async void`.